# Chrome audit - insufficient contrast ratio for disabled button

Tags: html, css

My accessibility rating is hurt due to this critical problem:

> Background and foreground colors do not have a sufficient contrast ratio.

Failing Elements:

```
button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled.wc-variation-selection-needed
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed">Add to cart</button>
```

**CSS for disabled class:**

```
.button.disabled, button.disabled {
    opacity: .5!important;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

I understand that increasing opacity will make this warning go away, but then the button will look like a regular button. Can I make something for Chrome to recognize it as disabled element and be okay with its opacity? Or Chrome audit doesn't forgive low contrast no matter what?

Comment: instead adding a classname, just add the disabled  attribute to the button. `<button> abled button</button> <button disabled>disabled button</button>`  , then for the CSS you want to override, you can filter a few rules with  `:not([disabled]){/*fancy style*/}` to avoid styling the disabled button ... a bit long for a comment, hope it's clear enoug

Comment: Adding `disabled` attribute in HTML works, Chrome audit no longer complains. You can post it as answer. I tried increasing opacity a lot and adding black borders (page background is white) with this increased opacity and it failed, so `disabled` attribute is definitely way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*from earlier comment:*

> instead adding a classname, you may  add the `disabled` attribute to the button, the browser does the styling itself.

```html
<button> abled button</button> <button disabled>disabled button</button>
```

> then for the CSS you want to override, you can filter a few rules with `:not([disabled]){/*fancy style*/}` to avoid styling the disabled button

```css
button:not([disabled]) {
  background: turquoise;
  border-color: tomato;
  color: gold;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button {/* mind specifity, here overwritten via the pseudoclass :not() */
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<button> abled button</button> <button disabled>disabled button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work with the `background-color` and a `rgba()` value in css. Hope it's an applicable solution for you.

Comment: The button has its background color and many other CSS rules set, I only mentioned CSS for disabled class.